# Outline in <input> tag and issues with size in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, outline

I realized a styled search box:
HTML

```css
@font-face {
 font-family:Beagle Normal;
 src:url(../data/beagle.woff);
}

#search input {
 border:1px solid #900;
 border-top-left-radius:14px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:14px;
 padding-left:14px;
 height:24px;
 display:inline;
 outline:0;
}

#search input:focus {
 outline:0;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}

#search button {
 background-color:#900;
 height:26px;
 display:inline;
 border:0;
 width:60px;
 position:relative;
 left:-8px;
 color:white;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">

  <form>
     <input type="search" placeholder="Search in the site" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I removed the outline which appears in Chrome when focused, but still the height of the  item gets reduced, just as that outline is still there.

How can i make it appear in all browsers just as it does with Firefox?

Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vZFE.png
IE11: equal to FF
Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ9aK.png

Answer (score 0):

You have the height of your input set to `24px`, it needs to be set to the same as your button, `26px` (or both need to be 24px). You may also need to use `box-sizing:border-box;` depending on your wider CSS.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Beagle Normal;
  src: url(../data/beagle.woff);
}
#search input {
  border: 1px solid #900;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* (you may or may not need this) */
  height: 26px; /* this should be the same... */
  display: inline;
  outline: 0;
}
#search input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
#search button {
  background-color: #900;
  height: 26px; /* as this... */
  box-sizing:border-box; /* (you may or may not need this) */
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  left: -8px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">

  <form>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search in the site" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No more problems: i solved using a chrome-only rule:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  #search input {
    height: 26px;
  }
}
```

This works very well.
@SW4
Doing just that solves the problem with Chrome, but it makes misbehave FF and IE instead. Thanks for your suggestion anyways.